# .htaccess condition based on subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to 301 redirect based upon a condition.

If in url there is a keyword **marketplace** after my domain then
it should be redirect as my domain and query string containing keywords.

For example

**http://mydomain.com/marketplace/query**

then it should be redirect as follows

http://mydomain.com/index.php?dir1=marketplace&dir2=query

query string  parameter name dir1,dir2.

Please help me .

Answer (score 1):

You may try this in one .htaccess file at root directory:

```php
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !index\.php               [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/marketplace/([^/]+)/?   [NC]
RewriteRule .*  index.php?dir1=marketplace&dir2=%1    [L]
```

For permanent redirection, replace `[L]` with `[R=301,L]`